# Consecutive instances for same user and same status - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Need a MYSQL query that will find all events in my database that are consecutive and have the same user_id and status_id. How can I find consecutive events while avoiding a loop?

The issue that I am having is that I don't know how to check for breaks between times. So if someone is available from 10:00 AM - 10:30 AM, then again from 11:00 AM - 12:30 PM how to prevent the system from just saying 10:00 AM - 12:30 PM.

We are using PHP and Javascript to create the calendar, but was hoping to have a single table view that we could use for numerous different queries.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'ID',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1568 ;


INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(1, 101, '2013-08-14', '23:00:00', 2);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(2, 101, '2013-08-14', '23:15:00', 2);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(3, 101, '2013-08-14', '23:30:00', 2);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(4, 101, '2013-08-14', '23:45:00', 2);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(5, 101, '2013-08-15', '00:00:00', 2);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(6, 101, '2013-08-15', '00:15:00', 1);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(7, 500, '2013-08-14', '23:45:00', 1);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(8, 500, '2013-08-15', '00:00:00', 1);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(9, 500, '2013-08-15', '00:15:00', 2);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(10, 500, '2013-08-15', '00:30:00', 2);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(11, 500, '2013-08-15', '00:45:00', 1);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(12, 101, '2013-08-15', '01:15:00', 1);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(13, 101, '2013-08-15', '01:30:00', 1);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(14, 101, '2013-08-15', '01:45:00', 1);
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES(15, 101, '2013-08-15', '02:00:00', 1);
```

Desired output

```
row |user_id | date_start | time_start | date_end   | time_end | status_id | duration
1   |101     |'2013-08-14'| '23:00:00' |'2013-08-15'|'00:15:00'| 2         | 5
2   |101     |'2013-08-15'| '00:15:00' |'2013-08-15'|'00:30:00'| 1         | 1
3   |500     |'2013-08-14'| '23:45:00' |'2013-08-15'|'00:15:00'| 1         | 2
4   |500     |'2013-08-15'| '00:15:00' |'2013-08-15'|'00:45:00'| 2         | 2
5   |500     |'2013-08-15'| '00:45:00' |'2013-08-15'|'01:00:00'| 2         | 1
6   |101     |'2013-08-15'| '01:15:00' |'2013-08-15'|'02:15:00'| 1         | 4
```

Comment: Your data causes duplicate primary key errors. Try testing it out at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Sorry about that, I created some fake data to provide a good sample set, but forgot to update the event_id. This has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to create a solution...ish. Please take a look and find a way that it could be optimized!

```
SELECT user1, user2, status_id, min(Timestamp1), Timestamp2, max(duration) FROM (
    SELECT x.user1, x.user2, x.status_id, x.Timestamp1, x.Timestamp2, min(x.difference) as duration
    FROM (

    SELECT e1.user_id AS user1, e2.user_id AS user2, e1.status_id, CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time) AS Timestamp1, CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time)AS Timestamp2,
    CAST(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time),CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time)) AS SIGNED)  AS 'difference'
    FROM `events` e1, `events` e2
    WHERE e1.user_id = e2.user_id AND e1.status_id = e2.status_id
    AND CAST(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time),CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time)) AS SIGNED) >= 0
    AND CAST(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time),CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time)) AS SIGNED) < 240000
    ORDER BY e1.user_id, e1.status_id, Timestamp1, Timestamp2) x,
    (

    SELECT e1.user_id AS user1, e2.user_id AS user2, e1.status_id, CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time) AS Timestamp1, CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time)AS Timestamp2,
    CAST(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time),CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time)) AS SIGNED)  AS 'difference'
    FROM `events` e1, `events` e2
    WHERE e1.user_id = e2.user_id AND e1.status_id = e2.status_id
    AND CAST(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time),CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time)) AS SIGNED) >= 0
    ORDER BY e1.user_id, e1.status_id, Timestamp1, Timestamp2) y

    WHERE x.user1 = y.user1 AND x.user2 = y.user2 AND x.Timestamp1 = y.Timestamp1
    AND ADDTIME(x.Timestamp2, '00:15:00') NOT IN (
      SELECT CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time)AS Timestamp2
      FROM `events` e1, `events` e2
      WHERE e1.user_id = e2.user_id AND e1.status_id = e2.status_id
      AND x.user1 = e1.user_id AND x.status_id = e1.status_id
      AND x.Timestamp1 = CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time)
      AND CAST(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(e2.date, " ", e2.time),CONCAT(e1.date, " ", e1.time)) AS SIGNED) >= 0)

    GROUP BY x.user1, x.user2, x.status_id, x.Timestamp1
    ) z
GROUP BY user1, user2, status_id, Timestamp2
```

Here is the results that it provides:

USER1   USER2   STATUS  MIN(TIMESTAMP1)         TIMESTAMP2              MAX(DURATION)

101     101     1       2013-08-15 00:15:00     2013-08-15 00:15:00     0

101     101     1       2013-08-15 01:15:00     2013-08-15 02:00:00     4500

101     101     2       2013-08-14 23:00:00     2013-08-15 00:00:00     10000

500     500     1       2013-08-14 23:45:00     2013-08-15 00:00:00     1500

500     500     1       2013-08-15 00:45:00     2013-08-15 00:45:00     0

500     500     2       2013-08-15 00:15:00     2013-08-15 00:30:00     1500